# Freezed: toJson custom value

Tags: flutter

I create my model with [Freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) package to shorter my code. I know there is a tool  [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/)  that help me create model, but i prefer to use freezed.

**Question:** How to do it in freezed if in toJson() method have custom value like `updatedAt.toIso8601String()`.
Here is my example, if I am doing it in manual without freezed.

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "date_installed": "${dateInstalled.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${dateInstalled.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${dateInstalled.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
        "date_tested": "${dateTested.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${dateTested.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${dateTested.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
        "updated_at": updatedAt.toIso8601String(),
        "groups": List<dynamic>.from(groups.map((x) => x)),
}
```

How to use freezed with custom value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

freezed uses json_serializable for handling JSON serialization/deserialization.

Usually the best way to customize it is by using "converters", along the lines of:

```dart
class Iso8601DateTimeConverter implements JsonConverter<DateTime, String> {
  const Iso8601DateTimeConverter();

  @override
  DateTime fromJson(String s) => ...;

  @override
  String toJson(DateTime dt) => dt.toIso8601String();
}

@freezed
class SomeClass ... {
  const factory SomeClass({
    @JsonKey("updated_at") 
    @Iso8601DateTimeConverter()
      required DateTime updatedAt,
  }) = ...
}
```

It's described in more detail in https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable#custom-types-and-custom-encoding